# angular 4 - Add numbers from a nested array of a model

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of Model. Each object of this model has array of another model.
I want to add all the respective number variables from nested array. My piece of code is as below

Model

TimesheetLogged.ts

```
export interface TimesheetLogged {
    ProjectId: string,   
    MondayHours: number,
    TuesdayHours: number,
    WednesdayHours: number,
    ThursdayHours: number,
    FridayHours: number,
    SaturdayHours: number,
    SundayHours: number   
}
```

Project.ts

```
import { TimesheetLogged } from "./TimesheetLogged";

export interface Project {
    ProjectId: number;  
    TimeLoggedHours: TimesheetLogged[];   
}
```

Piece of code from Component

```
public Projects: Project[];
//Get projects data from database and subscribe to Projects object  Successfully

let chartData: Array<number> = [];
    let mon:number= 0;
    let tue:number= 0;
    let wed:number= 0;
    let thu:number= 0;
    let fri:number= 0;
    let sat:number= 0;
    let sun:number= 0;

    this.Projects.forEach((empHours) => {
        empHours.TimeLoggedHours.forEach((hours) => {
            a => {
                mon += a.MondayHours;
                tue += a.TuesdayHours;
                wed += a.WednesdayHours;
                thu += a.ThursdayHours;
                fri += a.FridayHours;
                sat += a.SaturdayHours;
                sun += a.SundayHours;
            }  
        });            
    });
    chartData.push(mon);
    chartData.push(tue);
    chartData.push(wed);
    chartData.push(thu);
    chartData.push(fri);
    chartData.push(sat);
    chartData.push(sun);
```

However I am getting Sum of all number variables as

[object Array][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Any update required in this code. Any other simpler solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `a =>` lambda and use `mon += hours.MondayHours` etc. instead.

Otherwise, in your second `forEach` you just create a bunch of lambda functions instead of changing `mon`, `tue` etc.

```
this.Projects.forEach(empHours => {
        empHours.TimeLoggedHours.forEach(hours => {
                mon += hours.MondayHours;
                tue += hours.TuesdayHours;
                wed += hours.WednesdayHours;
                thu += hours.ThursdayHours;
                fri += hours.FridayHours;
                sat += hours.SaturdayHours;
                sun += hours.SundayHours;
        });            
    });
```